# How to create a batch file that wil automatically install office,java and photoshop without a box asking hundreds of preferences

Tags: batch-file, command-line, parameters, installation, command-line-arguments

How do I create a batch file that wil automatically install office,java and photoshop without a box asking hundreds of preferences?

for example:

```
@ECHO OFF
start J:\Batch\test.exe
```

But if I do that it asks: Select setup language
What is the code for passing that box and automatically select English? I searched on the web but I couldn't find it. Does anyone know it?
Here is the exe file I'm testing: http://pxc-coding.com/downloads/tweaks-for-skype/Tweaks-for-Skype-1.0.0.2-Setup.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I' not going to download and run an unknown program.

But you can try this:

1) run the program

2) note every answer

3) put those answers into a textfile (each answer in an own line, no empty lines - except you just hit "enter" to an answer)

4) run `test.exe <answers.txt`

once it works, you can distribute `answers.txt` with your package.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it with Tweaks for skype because its small, and it asks for language input. Now I've folowed you steps and these are the thing I have to do:

Comment: OK,
Next,
I accept the agreement,
Next,
Next,
Next,
Next,
Next,
Create a desktop icon,
Next,
Next,
Install,
Finish,

Comment: But then it still asks to choose a language, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: oh, it's a GUI? Then there is no pure batch-solution, unless `test.exe` supports commandline parameters for that (like for example `/silent` or `/language=english`). You will find them in the manual or in the sourcecode. If you are very lucky, `test /?` will tell you.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I've found it, I'll gonna look at it and let you know if it worked. ☺

Comment: I've found a few codes by doing /?, but I don't get much further with it. Thanks for all! I'll mark it as anwered cause I can't get much further